# Angle bisector in a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

For the angle bisector $I_a$ in a triangle $ABC$ it holds 
$$I_a^2 = \frac{bc}{(b+c)^2}[(b+c)^2 - a^2]$$
If $I$ is the incenter, I wonder if there exist similar formula for the part $AI^2$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539226/proving-the-length-of-angle-bisector

Comment: Also, $AI=\frac{r}{\sin \frac{A}2}$ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put weights $a$, $b$, $c$ on the three vertices $A$, $B$, $C$. Their center of gravity is $I$. The center of gravity of $B$ and $C$ is the intersection of $AI$ with $BC$.

Therefore, $AI : I_a = \dfrac{b+c}{a+b+c}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. So the formula is $$AI^2 = \frac{bc}{(a+b+c)^2}[(b+c)^2 - a^2].$$