# Synthetic proof of a bisector length

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, alternative-proof

In a exam the following was asked and I found a proof based on a law of cosines. Is there a pure synthetic proof without trigonometry?

$ABC$ is a triangle with side lengths $CA=a,CB=b$. $D\in AB$ is a point such that $CD$ is a bisector of $ACB$ and $CD=k$. Suppose that $AD=x$ and $DB=y$. Prove that $k^2=ab-xy$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on considering [Stewart's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart's_theorem) a result in synthetic geometry or trigonometry.

It directly follows from the law of cosines, so the problem boils down to considering the law of cosines as a result in synthetic geometry or trigonometry. In fact, it can be proved only through the definition of the cosine function (not its algebraic or analytic properties) and a simple [dissection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissection_problem) argument (a variation on the usual proof of the Pythagorean theorem), hence I would say trigonometry is not *really* involved.

For a pure synthetic proof you may look at samarth srivastava's answer to [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539226/proving-the-length-of-angle-bisector).